# WebdriverIO -[ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END] with node 12.18.4 and wdio 6.12.1

Tags: mocha.js, webdriver-io, wdio, wdiosync

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:266:14) at RunnerStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:315:5) at RunnerTransformStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:719:22) at RunnerTransformStream.emit (events.js:314:20) at RunnerTransformStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12) at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:298:12) at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9) at RunnerTransformStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10) at RunnerTransformStream.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:152:32) at RunnerTransformStream._transform (C:\dev\repositories\login.dfe.ui-tests\node_modules@wdio\local-runner\build\transformStream.js:15:14

`Before used to run node 10.23.3 and wdio 6.12.1 where it is able to run multiple tests in suite without issues. now upgrading node version to 12.28.4 causes the below issue with same wdio version.`
`Is there anything i need to update? we running nodejs project with wdio framework to run mutliple tests.`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To make things run more smoothly, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of how SO works and especially [How To Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please edit your question with more detail so others could help you out.